# Riemannian metric from spherical metric after projection on plane

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I want to show that the meric

$$ds^2=R^2\frac{(a^2+v^2)du^2-2uvdudv+(a^2+u^2)dv^2}{(a^2+u^2+v^2)^2}$$

results if one projects the sphere of radius $R$ from its center to a plane having distance $a$ from this center.

My attempt:

I can take

$$(u,v,w)\mapsto (\gamma u, \gamma v, \gamma a)$$

as the projection with

$$(\gamma u)^2+(\gamma v)^2+(\gamma a)^2=R^2$$

So I can write

$$\gamma=\frac{R}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2+a^2}}$$

But I don't see how I can get the above metric from this...

Comment: Your formula is incorrect. So to get the metric pulled back to the plane, you'll want the (correct) mapping from the (portion of the) plane to the sphere. Of course, you only get the portion of the sphere lying above the plane, right?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I don't think the metric is false. There you have a source on page 7. of this paper: http://www.dm.unibo.it/~arcozzi/beltrami_sent1.pdf So it should be a metric on the sphere after projecting on the plane

Comment: Oh, so $a>R$? Your formula for the projection is still wrong, regardless.

Comment: I'm with Ted, in that something about the projection looks strange: As written the projection does not depend on $w$, and it appears not to take values in a plane. Should the projection formula instead have third component $\gamma w$ with $\gamma w = a$, or something...?